# From xss to rce in client side

Tags: linux, xss, javascript

I found a desktop application in Linux w/c getsvand that displays items from site xyz. xyz is vulnerable to XSS and code injected there is also executed on client side's desktop app.similar to this scenario https://twitter.com/taviso/status/657001717427339265 .......My question is how one can elevate this to exec os commands via client side desktop app?